# Navigate to a view before current view appears in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to navigate to a view based on a condition - whether the user is logged in or not, and I am trying to navigate from ViewA to ViewB (assuming the user is logged in already) without ViewA showing, but I do want to technically go through ViewA.
I tried navigating from `.OnAppear`, but as the name suggests, ViewA appears first for half a second, and only then it navigates.

Usually, with UIKit, I used to write the condition in `viewDidLoad` of ViewA, so ViewA wouldn't even appear, and will automatically navigate to ViewB without ViewA showing up.

Is there a way to navigate from ViewA -> ViewB without ViewA showing at all?

Reproducible example:

**ViewA:**

```
struct ViewA: View {
    @State private var isLoggedIn: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewB(), isActive: $isLoggedIn) { EmptyView() }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            if User.shared.isLoggedIn //assuming this is true {
               isLoggedIn.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewB:**

```
struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
          Text("View B")    
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to assign to it in ViewA's init. In fact, I would probably just use an if/else statement in ViewA's body, rather than a NavigationView -- but I don't know your constraints and maybe in the real code you need the back button.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Thanks for the reply, I tried it, unfortunately it doesn’t work, the init is running before the view contents such as the navigationlink, and unfortunately I need the NavigationView

Comment: Try changing `VStack` for `LazyVStack` and `ScrollView`

Comment: @loremipsum unfortunately, that also didn't seem to work

Comment: You can wrap your `NavigationView` in the body of `ViewA` with `if User.shared.isLoggedIn {.......}`. `ViewA` will appear but no content will be shown.

Comment: @HunterLion Thanks, this is not quite the ideal solution, but it is good enough for now.